# Empty WSDL response from request

Tags: php, api, wsdl, asmx

So, I have recieved a WSDL link with username/password credentials.
I have created a php site which I think requests results from the WSDL with given username and password.

However, my website is blank.

HTML:

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Testing wsdl</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

$options = array(
     'hid denwith a space\username1' => $userName,
     'pass#word' => $password,
);

    $client = new SoapClient("https://online.infracontrol.com/Areas/Parking/Services/V1/ParkingInfo.asmx?wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
    $result = $client('ListSites', $options);
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

PHP-code is based on given info as follows:

```
POST /Areas/Parking/Services/V1/ParkingInfo.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: online.infracontrol.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <ListSites xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <userName>string</userName>
      <password>string</password>
    </ListSites>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

But why is my website empty when I update it?

And how can I use this result as data for my map?

Comment: Is it completely blank? Have you checked the source? Do you see your HTML? If not, check your web servers error log to see if there's any error messages. This: `$client('ListSites', $options);` looks a bit odd. Shouldn't it be `$client->__soapCall('ListSites', $options);`? I also don't really get what you're doing in your `$options`-array.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I can see my other html. Options array is for username and password.

Comment: How would the server be able to know what this is `hid denwith a space\username1`? That should be the key `username`, no? I would recommend that you read through the manual about PHP soap.

Comment: Well the username has a space in it as well as a backslash

Comment: But that's the parameter _name_, not value. It should be `['username' => 'your username', 'password' => 'your-password']`.

Comment: Sorter out to

     $params = array(
       "username" => 'hidden \ username1',
       "password" => 'pass#word',
     );

Still no response

Does this site help? https://online.infracontrol.com/Areas/Parking/Services/V1/ParkingInfo.asmx

I have also gotten this from get Types()
0]=> string(56) "struct ListSites { string userName; string password;